# Передача параметров в PHP по ссылке вида http://somesite.ru/script.js

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую! Такая задача, есть сайт php и сайт html. Нужно на сайте html добавить код примерно такого вида

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://php.ru/script.js"></script>
```

script.js - получает переменные, на их основе получает данные из базы и возвращает js-код

Для примера: гугл адсенс.

Вопрос, как получить переменные a, b, c в скрипте script.js?

Comment: Разве они там не будут видны? Я так делал, следующий скрипт видит эти переменные.

Comment: На стороне клиента может будут видны, но мне то нужно отдать их php сайту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто сделать
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://сайт/script.php?данные"></script>` 
и исходя из данных генерировать яваскрипт из пхп
добавка. ввести перезват тогда по имени script.js в файле .htaccess с передачей скрипту пхп параметров [L]

Comment: Да, это запасной вариант, если основной не получиться сделать.

Comment: а основной это какой?

Comment: Который указал в задаче

Comment: если необходимо именно окончание js тогда в конфиге сервера пишем что файлы js надо обрабатывать как файлы php и опять таки все будет то же самое. только простой яваскрипт файл тогда загрузить будет уже нельзя из за обработки его пхпшкой

Comment: лучше тогда стать извращенцем и ввести расширение .jsh на сервер заставив пхп его обрабатывать. и на него ссылаться когда надо яваскрипт генерировать с параметрами. пусть пхп его обрабатывает. будет не так в глаза бросаться)))

Comment: Это уже мания красоты, не очень хотелось параметры в строке передавать, но видимо так действительно проще. Остановлюсь на этом. Спасибо!

А js-файл только для вида, этот урл php-скриптом обрабатывается.

Comment: просто если у вас все на одном домене то можете параметры при выводе хтмл (опять таки генирить хтмл надо из пхп) задать переменные в сессии а файл яваскрипта перехватывать правилом в файле .htaccess и генерировать скрипт. но тогда нельзя будет задавать два файла на одной странице ибо смешаются переменные и скрипт сгенерится исходя из всех) переменные после генерации уничтожать в сессии само собой!

Answer (score 2):

проще всего, без правки конфигов сервера.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://php.ru/script.js"></script>
```

меняем на:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://php.ru/script.php?var1=val1&var2=val2"></script>
```

где var1,2 название переменных а val1,2 соответвенно их значение

**Добавлено:**
если имеется ввиду динамическая подгрузка скриптов, то проще всего юзать jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("head").append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://php.ru/script.php?var1=val1&var2=val2\"><\/script>");
        });
</script>
```